# In NONCLIENTMETRICS, what's the difference between status font, message font, and caption font?

Tags: c++, windows, internationalization, fonts

Ok, just found out that using `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` is the wrong thing to actually use as a default GUI font.... there's a [NONCLIENTMETRICS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724506.aspx) structure that I've been told to use instead, but I'm not sure which of the fonts returned there I should use -- i.e. what's the difference between the status font, message font, and caption fonts, and when should I use each?

Comment: "wrong thing to do for this" is absolutely meaningless, you haven't said what "this" is... although using `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` is pretty much wrong for anything, so maybe it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: @Ben: Well, I meant to actually use as a default GUI font lol (i.e. as done in Petzold's book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description is pretty clear, isn't it?

> lfMenuFont A pointer to a LOGFONT
>   structure that contains information
>   about the font used in menu bars.
>
> lfStatusFont A pointer to a LOGFONT
>   structure that contains information
>   about the font used in status bars and
>   tooltips.
>
> lfMessageFont A pointer to a LOGFONT
>   structure that contains information
>   about the font used in message boxes.

Use the menu fonts for drop-down menus, use the status font for status lines, use the message font for message boxes.

**Edit**: The description of lfCaptionFont and lfSmCaptionFont is unfortunately self-referential:

> lfCaptionFont A pointer to a LOGFONT
>   structure that contains information
>   about the caption font.

The caption of a window is the rectangle above the client area, where the window title and the close buttons are displayed. This uses the caption font. The message font is used in message boxes.

Comment: 1. That does not mention the caption fonts. 2. What's the difference between a caption and a message? Seems like the same thing to me...

Comment: @Billy: Open up "advanced appearance settings" in Control Panel, there you can interact with sizes of different things and see how it affects a sample desktop+application.  Caption fonts are for window titlebar text.  Compare [the second and third parameters of the `MessageBox` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently "MS Shell Dlg" is a magic font name that maps to the default font {on all moderately recent versions of Windows, although XP introduced "MS Shell Dlg 2", but not all language versions :(}  -- [preemptive obligatory xkcd link](http://xkcd.com/541/) -- there's some information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/07/436435.aspx) and more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374112.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282187).

But you should probably just go to [Michael Kaplan's recommendation: If your app doesn't need to run on Win9x, just use Tahoma](http://www.siao2.com/2006/03/18/554308.aspx).  Of course you'll still need to get the preferred size from `SystemParametersInfo`.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think "MS Shell Dlg" gives you Segoe UI on newer versions of Windows, which you need if you want to blend in.  Personally, I get NONCLIENTMETRICS and use the message box font for any general UI text.  In practice, the message box font, status font, and menu font are often the same.